# Wordpress/Woocommerce. Отключить отображение товаров на главной

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, вёрстка, woocommerce

Всем привет. Подскажите, сейчас разбираюсь в основах построения магазина на Woocommerce для Wordpress. Тему взял i-craft.
И в ходе создания возникла проблема.

1) Как возможно изменить отображение на главной странице магазина категорий и товаров(в настройках Woocommerce есть параметр переключения отображения категории/товары, но отключить нельзя).
Возможен ли вариант отключения ?

В БД нашел отвечающий за отображение на главной страницы товаров/категорий

***`*wp_options  = >  'woocommerce_shop_page_display', 'subcategories', 'yes'*`***

Но способ отключения так и не нашел.

2) Сейчас данные категории и товары отображаются на главной под моим контентом, который пишу в редакторе страниц WP.(т.е. сначала контент страницы, затем товары). Где можно переместить контент вниз, а товары поднять вверх?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не стоит сразу лезть в БД. Там можно очень больших дров наломать. Начать изучение WooCommerce стоит с [шорткодов](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/) и [хуков](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html).

По вопросам.

1. На главной странице магазина отключить вывод информации WooCommerce нельзя. На то он и магазин. У Вас должна быть главная страница сайта http://mysite.ru и страница магазина, указанная в меню: http://mysite.ru/shop
2. Когда Вы разделите главную страницу сайта и магазина указанным выше образом, вопрос отпадет сам собой. На главной странице сайта сможете разместить свой контент и в удобном месте (хоть в середине его) вставить шорткод с главными товарами, например, такой:

[product_category category="sistemy-zzz" orderby="menu_order" order="asc"  per_page="4"]

Это рабочий пример с одного из моих сайтов. Данный шорткод выводит 4 товара из категории sistemy-zzz в порядке, прописанном в админке, по возрастанию.

Текст главной страницы у вас может выглядеть так:

Спасибо, что посетили наш замечательный магазин!
Главные товары ниже

[product_category category="sistemy-zzz" orderby="menu_order" order="asc"  per_page="4"]

А полностью магазин доступен через ссылку в меню сайта.